# error C2908: explicit specialization; '' has already been instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, specialization

I have a simple template singleton class , I simplified if to keep is simple to read ( removed safeguard , asserts, etc.. it's not the subject of the question )

```
template< class  T> T* Create();

template <class T>
class CSingleton
{
    public:
    static  T*      CreateInstance() { return m_instance = Create<T>(); }
    static  void    DestroyInstance() { delete m_instance;}

    protected:
    static T* m_instance;
};
```

As you can see I use a global function T* Create() to new the pointer as my class could be an abstract class. so if instead I define CreateInstance like this :

```
static  T*      CreateInstance() { return m_instance = new T; }
```

It will generate an error that I can't instantiate an abstract class.

So here a very simple exemple that generate the error ,
The class :

```
class MyClass : public CSingleton<MyClass>
{
};
```

and the definition of the global function in my cpp

```
template< > MyClass* Create< MyClass >()
{
    return nullptr;// just for the compilation demonstration
}
```

If I dont define this , the linker will output error that it can't find Create(), If I define the function, I get this error :

```
error C2908:  explicit specialization; 'T *Create<T>(void)' has already been instantiated
error C2908:         with
error C2908:         [
error C2908:             T=MyClass
error C2908:         ]
```

I'm stuck for 2 hours on this problem, I can't find a solution, i googled and search on StackOverflow, coudln't find a similar problem and solution.

Cheers,
Seb

Comment: Templates and their specializations should be defined in header files (.h not .cpp). Can you show the contents of each .h and .cpp files of this minimal example? Looks like an implicit instantiation is taking place, due to wrong placing of the global template function Create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those classes are in a DLL library, but I got the compiler / link error when building the library only.

I forgot to check the dllimport/dllexport signatures. Adding those in front of my Singleton class and Create func solved this error.